# Visa extension after injury

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

I have a Schengen visa that is valid from June 15 to July 7. I had a serious leg injury, so I would like to know if my visa's validity period is extended if I send a mail to my consulate and tell my whole story.

Comment: Are you already in the Schengen Area? Can you provide a doctor's notice that you should avoid traveling by plane?

Comment: I would think that contacting your consulate would be the very best first step.

Answer (score 4):

If you are already in the Schengen area, you can apply for an extension of your visa. You will need to search for the information of the country that you are staying in, however.

For example, for Berlin (Germany), [this page](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324785/en/) lists the point of contact and the how the process works.